# ASCIIで記述した回路を図面に変換するアルゴリズムを探す

Tags: アルゴリズム, hdl

現在ASCIIで記述したノードとノードとのつながりを図面に変換するアルゴリズムを探します。
特に、Synopsys VerdiのようにVerilog HDL/VHDLコードからきれいな理解しやすい回路図を生成したい。どんなアルゴリズムでこれを果たすことができますか。
ノードの形は何でも構いません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「何らかの記述を元に図面を作成する」と「見やすい配置で回路図を作成する」では手法が異なるように思いますが、今回はどちらがターゲットなのでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick 主な目標は、コードから図面を作成します。yosysも回路図を生成できることが知っていますが、verdiのほうがきれいです。もうverdiに慣れましたので。